# tokio-postgre и запрос к базе

Tags: postgresql, rust, actix-web

Есть такой код модуля(для работы с базой данных):

```
use tokio_postgres::{NoTls, Error};

pub async fn hello() -> Result<(), Error> {

    //println!("hello() from db.rs");

    // Connect to the database.
    let (client, connection) =
        tokio_postgres::connect("host=localhost user=postgres", NoTls).await?;

    // The connection object performs the actual communication with the database,
    // so spawn it off to run on its own.
    tokio::spawn(async move {
        if let Err(e) = connection.await {
            eprintln!("connection error: {}", e);
        }
    });

    // Now we can execute a simple statement that just returns its parameter.
    let rows = client
        .query("SELECT $1::TEXT", &[&"hello world"])
        .await?;

    println!("{:?}", rows);

    // And then check that we got back the same string we sent over.
    let value: &str = rows[0].get(0);
    assert_eq!(value, "hello world");

    Ok(())
}
```

Вопрос:
Каким образом в данном случае должно быть прописано обращение к базе данных?
(в гайде ничего об этом не сказано - либо я не до конца разобрался.)
https://docs.rs/tokio-postgres/0.5.5/tokio_postgres/
Какие механизмы в данном случае будут защищать обращение к базе от sql иньекций?
Необходим самый простой пример использования в общем.

Comment: от инъекций должно защищать то что запрос конструируется `query`, а не ручками... соответственно он должен корректно эскейпить все непотребные символы в пользовательских данных... а за остальное — не понятно в чём суть вопроса...

Comment: http://joxi.ru/YmEgJPahMMWOlA
суть следующая.
есть таблица в базе - вопрос как обратится к ней и вытащить что то или наоборот положить туда + что бы это был правильный безопасный подход?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> joxi.ru/YmEgJPahMMWOlA суть следующая. есть таблица в базе - вопрос как обратится к ней и вытащить что то или наоборот положить туда + что бы это был правильный безопасный подход?

В первом приближении достаточно просто исполнять обычные запросы с помощью `execute`/`query`:

```
let num = client.execute( "INSERT INTO my_first_table (first_column, second_column) \
                           VALUES ($1, $2)",
                         &[&"mouse", &12] ).await?;

assert_eq!(num, 1);

let rows = client.query( "SELECT first_column, second_column  FROM my_first_table  \
                          WHERE first_column != $1",
                         &[&"Cheese"] ).await?;

for r in rows.iter() {
  let row: (&str, i64) = (r.get(0), r.get(1));
  println!("{} : {}", row.0, row.1);
}
```

[`Client::execute()`](https://docs.rs/tokio-postgres/0.5.5/tokio_postgres/struct.Client.html#method.execute) и [`Client::query()`](https://docs.rs/tokio-postgres/0.5.5/tokio_postgres/struct.Client.html#method.query) сами экранируют все символы/кавычки и т.п. Для определённых ситуаций стоит использовать [подготовку запросов](https://docs.rs/tokio-postgres/0.5.5/tokio_postgres/struct.Client.html#method.prepare), [конвееризацию](https://docs.rs/tokio-postgres/0.5.5/tokio_postgres/#pipelining) итп, но и исполнение одиночных запросов — абсолютно нормальная практика.

---

**Не стоит** напрямую подготавливать запрос с помощью `format!`, а затем исполнять его с помощью [`Client::simple_query()`](https://docs.rs/tokio-postgres/0.5.5/tokio_postgres/struct.Client.html#method.simple_query). Это грозит соответствующим весельем:

```
client.simple_query( format!("SELECT *  FROM my_first_table WHERE first_column != '{}'",
                             "Cheese'; DROP TABLE my_first_table; --" ));
```

Comment: http://joxi.ru/DrlK6ZoCyyEaDA
пока что вот такое решение вызывает ошибку - в чем там причина может быть?

Comment: + мне необходимо понять - где я могу посмотреть что я у базы вытаскиваю - в вашем коде как я понимаю этого нет.
Я похожее что то соорудил только без ошибок у себя - и там не отображается то что я из базы вытаскиваю:
http://joxi.ru/p27ZKN9UNN6yDm
а отображен только параметр текстовый который я в запросе использую к базе.

Comment: вроде разобрался:
http://joxi.ru/KAg5e6oHKKJ1Wm
вот так - все работает.

Comment: поправил... правда нормального inline'ового синтаксиса для этого не нашёл...

Comment: все равно ошибка вылетает

Comment: @MikeKharkov, какая?

Comment: http://joxi.ru/KAg5e6oHKKxW4m
там их штук 60
попутно еще 1 вопрос:
http://joxi.ru/LmGgJPehllzPJm
как избавится от этого предупреждения?
http://joxi.ru/L215QxzH00j9D2
у меня в главном модуле вызов функции стоит (из доп. модуля.)

Comment: про ошибку — или в rust'е заменить `i64` на `i32`, или в базе сделать поле типа `BIGINT`... по предупреждению — обработать результат, например, просто добавив `?`...

Comment: на счет предупреждения - куда именно добавить необходимо "?"  ?

Comment: @MikeKharkov к вызову `hello.await()` в main'е... только возвращаемый тип ошибки должен быть совместимый...

Comment: http://joxi.ru/8AnadRoSyozxk2
а где это(возвращаемый тип ошибки) надо прописать и как конкретно?

Comment: @MikeKharkov, https://doc.rust-lang.ru/book/ch09-02-recoverable-errors-with-result.html